# Search CSV for string and assign column of cell to a list

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a program which will scan a CSV for IMG SRC tags and then test them for their response. I'm stuck with this portion of the code which ideally searches the entire CSV document for a 'SRC' cell (to find the IMG SRC tags), and then assigns that column as the one to run the tests on. Here is my attempt:

```
src_check = ('SRC')
imp_check = ('Impression')

with open("ORIGINAL.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if src_check in column[:]:
                list = [column[j] for column in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

My confusion comes from the fact that when I manually enter the column number into my program, it runs as it should: it tests each cell of the column/list and neatly writes the results next to each tag tested.

To reiterate my problem, I would like this snippet to find the first IMG SRC cell of the entire CSV. Then it would note the number of that column, and I can assign the entire column to a list for the tests to be run. For example, the process after would be:

1. Column 16 has been identified as carrying the IMG SRC tags.
2. Assign the contents of the column to a list.
3. Run request tests on list.

Right now the test result column does not line up with the tags that it tests. Does anyone have a better method in finding a cell based on a string and then assigning the column as a list, in-line with the cells it's testing?

Comment: Please provide sample CSV data. Is there no header?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that both csvReader are using the same file descriptor and thus the offset is all messed up.
Try to do one thing after another (and/or reset the offset via csvfile.seek(0)) and it should work.

```
src_check = ('SRC')
with open("ORIGINAL.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    col_index = -1
    for row in reader:
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if src_check in column:
                col_index = j
                break
        if col_index != -1:
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError("Column not found")
    csvfile.seek(0)
    col_vals = [column[col_index] for column in reader]
    print col_vals
```

*Edit: Also you shouldn't use the name of builtin (like "list") as a variable name.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the column index first and than rewind the file to the begnning before you read the column:

```
src_check = ('SRC')
with open("ORIGINAL.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
         if src_check in row:
             col = row.index(src_check)
             break
     else:
         raise ValueError('SRC not found')
     # go back to beginning of the file
     csfile.seek(0)
     values = [row[col] for row in reader]
```